# How to Change Font Color in the Left Menu

Tags: spcolor

When I created a site, the menu was automatically pink (see image).  How do I change the color?

[image]

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you could change this.

1. Click the Cog Icon > Change the Look > choose a layout and customize the colors from there.
2. For more complete control you can follow the steps [here](http://eimagine.com/how-to-display-the-master-page-link-in-site-settings-for-sharepoint-2013/) to enable the Master Page settings, then upload and set a CSS file where you target the side options with any color.